# C# Entityframework how to include based on condition

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table with one to many to many relation ie 
ManyToMany table:

MenuGroup

```
menuid  groupid
1       4
1       5
```

Menu

```
menuid  name
1       One
2       Two
```

Group

```
groupid name
4       group4
5       group5
```

Groupuser

```
groupid     userid
4           101
4           103
5           102
```

i would like to get all menus of the user 101
ie

```
Menuid  groupid name
1       4       group4
```

But i am getting the wrong out put eventhough writing the correct join queries. Can anyone help what am i doing wrong here?

```
Menuid  groupid name
1       4       group4
1       5       group5

(from m in context.Menus
      join mg in context.MenuGroup on m.MenuId equals mg.MenuId
      join gu in context.Groupuser on mg.GroupId equals gu.GroupId
      where gu.UserId == 101
      select m);
```

i would like to include only this particular user's group details though this menu is in other group as well.

my expected output in json would be

```
{
    "menuid": 1,
    "name": "One",
    "groups":[
        {
            "groupid":4,
"name":"group4"
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: So add `where gu.GroupId = 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linq query looks good, I suspect data issue, but would you like to try the following query to see what you get back. This following query requires navigation properties declared.

```
var userMenus = context.GroupUser.Where(u=>u.UserId = 101).SelectMany(g=>g.Group.Menus
           .Select(m=> new {Menu=m.MenuId, GroupId=g.GroupId,GroupName=g.Group.name))
           .ToList();
```

In case you want the complete Menu object

```
var userMenus = context.GroupUser.Where(u=>u.UserId = 101).SelectMany(g=>g.Group.Menus
           .Select(m=> new {Menu=m.Menu, GroupId=g.GroupId,GroupName=g.Group.name))
           .ToList();
```

In case you don't care about Group columns and just want Menu then

```
var userMenus = context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 101)
               .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus.Select(m=>m.Menu));
```

Comment: Thank you. This brings back all groupid and menuid for this user. both groupid and menuid are of the user. i dont find any groupid belongs to some other user. it is strange the final result brings other groupid.

Comment: So you mean the suggested answer is also not working..?

Comment: U mean like this: from m in context.Menus
                          join mg in context.GroupMenus on m.MenuId equals mg.MenuId
                          join gu in context.GroupUsers.Where(gu=>gu.UserId == dbUser.UserId) on mg.GroupId equals gu.GroupId
                          where gu.UserId == dbUser.UserId &&
                          m.Customer.ExternalId == user.OrganisationId
                          select m

Comment: No. it didnt worked. it is bringing back all groups related to menu

Comment: I have edited the answer to return the results exactly as you wanted, can you try this and let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: sorry I dont get you where you want me to place your code. umean inside the linq from query in join?

Comment: that will just replaces the query you wrote. see what you get in userMenus variable.

Comment: Thanks. But how i need the complete menu object with other properties

Comment: Instead returning anonymous object can i return menu like context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 2).SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus.Select(m=>m.Menu));

Comment: Yes,context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 2).SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus);  you an do that too if you do not want any group columns. You can either list all the columns you want in the inside .Select or Just select Full Menu as I stated above , but I would recommend to list columns you want instead of returning full menu...Anyway its up to you based on your requirements.

Comment: If this answers your question please select as the answer.

Comment: If i write this in a method. may i know what should be the return typ? currently i am returning IQueryable<Menu>

Comment: It depends, if you want the query to execute later(but not inside this method) you can return IQueryable<Menu> without.ToList() at the end of the query,  if you want the query to execute rightaway you can return IList<Menu> with.ToList() at the end of the query

Comment: Because i am work on existing code. sometime there could be duplicate menus. so they are using distinct(). how to achieve the same in this kind of query. and after getting the iqueryable can i select groupid, groupname as in the select separately? sorry for keeping puttin glot of question around this

Comment: Moreover i am getting error saying cannot convert GroupMenu to Menu when i return iqueryable

Comment: If you want the groupId, GroupName, then new custom type with full Menu and GroupId, GroupName as return type using the second query mentioned in the answer might be better. To eliminate any duplicates of menus in data, inside SelectMany, use .Menus.Distinct().Select( ...

Comment: Thanks. I am getting cannot implicity convert GroupMenu to Menu error when i use             var rest = context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 2)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus.Distinct());

Comment: can i use something like this? result = context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 2)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus.Distinct().Select(x=>x.Menu));

Comment: Yes, In your case looks like Group.Menu is actually a group Menu, so yes result = context.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == 2) .SelectMany(g => g.Group.Menus.Select(x=>x.Menu).Distinct())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125345/discussion-between-mukil-deepthi-and-pjobs).